# Fade Background Transition and Hover Div effect

Tags: jquery, css

Working on this 5 option block landing page and each block has it's own image for that category.

The goal is to have it load with the first one (m1) loaded, then when you mouse over another block the block div would blink twice very fast, very digital like and get white in it's blink. Hoping that makes sense? The whole div is a link, not sure if I did it the best way, but it seems to work!

In addition, the backgrounds are swapping but I would like them to be a little "smoother" in the transitions between the backgrounds that are swapped via jQuery.

I don't even know if I wrote the jQuery correctly so looking for comments on that also.

Thanks so much! Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/da09ewLn/

```
<div class="cat_bg">
  <div id="m1" class="clickable">
    <a href="link.php"> </a>Option 1</div>
  <div id="m2" class="clickable">
    <a href="link.php"> </a>Option 2</div>
  <div id="m3" class="clickable">
    <a href="link.php"> </a>Option 3</div>
  <div id="m4" class="clickable">
    <a href="link.php"> </a>Option 4</div>
  <div id="m5" class="clickable">
    <a href="link.php"> </a>Option 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/da09ewLn/4/) and added some few lines of jquery and css.

if it so the you want to do the transitions via **jQuery**.
just add in your jquery `.css()` line the 
`transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s; /*0.3s or no. of delays of your choice. */`

`.css()` in your jQuery would look like this:

`.css({'background-image': 'url(http://i.imgur.com/cyNC3xZ.jpg)', 'transition': 'all ease-in-out 0.3s'})`

I recommend adding the transition in css instead for they will be alot 
if you also want the transition to work in other browsers.

```
-webkit-transition:all ease-in-out 0.3s;
-moz-transition:all ease-in-out 0.3s;
-o-transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
```

Comment: Thank you, but the effect transition is not right. The easing in and out of the background images is to much.  it has is too much, how can they just fade in and out as you hover over the to make a selection? Thanks Mark!!

Comment: im not sure i get you. how do you exactly want it to look like when hovered?

Comment: What I mean is, the background seems to act like an accordion and stretches when it changes from picture to picture. Instead of just simply fading the current one out while fading the next one from the mouseover.

Comment: Hoping for some more assistance, I can't seem to get the background to fade instead of zoomin/out on rollover. Thanks all.